# Product quantity bound to colors and sizes table structures SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-design

I've been thinking about how I'll be able to create products with sizes and colors which will match the max quantity of a product (or their total will be the max.quantity ).

Let's say I got a product which has a total 12 quantity.

In those 12 there are **colors** such as **RED,BLUE,GREEN** and  there will be **3 sizes** such as **SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE**.

**Like :**

```
3x RED SMALL
1x RED LARGE

2x BLUE SMALL
2x BLUE MEDIUM
1x BLUE LARGE

1x GREEN SMALL
1x GREEN MEDIUM
1x GREEN LARGE
Total:12X
```

Now,

- sometimes products wont have any colors, only sizes
- Sometimes only colors, no sizes.
- Sometimes no color neither sizes.

What is the best way of structuring tables to acheive this?

**I think like :**

```
Products:
PID,name,(maxqty?)

Sizes:
SID, name

Colors:
CID,name

Used_sizes_colors:
PID,SID,CID,qty
```

How would you do this?

Comment: Do you need to record other information that is unique to each "instance" of the product? In other words, do you need a row for each of the 3 red small products?

Comment: Is max quantity a limit you want to enforce as rows are inserted or updated or is it a total you want to calculate based on the existing rows?

Comment: I am not sure yet about the max quantity. if i need it or not. what is best ? becuase sometimes there wont be any sizes or colors then there are no rows to count to set the max quantity. do u get me?

Comment: If there aren't any rows, the count is zero. That's not a problem. In that case, your table structure looks alright and you can create the ``maxqty`` column in a view over the ``Products`` table.

Comment: what do you think about this: IF i want to use size or color (or both) then i wil let maxQTY to be null. but if i rather want to haveno colors or sizes then ill just enter the value of quantity in maxQTY

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sometimes there are products that doesn't need to be set to a size or color. So on those products I'll just add the full quantitity directly in the products table. What do you think ?

Comment: I decided to drop the column maxQty and rename the table Used_sizes_colors to Quantities, then if there are no size or color i'll just let them be null.

Comment: This sounds like a document-based approach. MySQL isn't the best place to do this... I can think of two options: either to keep all properties as json object (but querying it in MySQL won't be pretty) or to have a separate table with attributes (0 or more attributes per object). This gives the required flexibility, but you have to pay for this with more pain while retrieving and changing your data. Plus having different attribute values in the same column isn't great for integrity checking.

Comment: lol i do not agree with you, sql is the approach to use. and I've solved it.

Comment: @Kilise I you have solved it, post this as an answer and later accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to drop the column maxQty and rename the table Used_sizes_colors to Quantities, then count the quantity from  the quantties table.